# Seemingly simple question: are the "neighborhoods" of a neighborhood function actually neighborhoods in the topology it induces?

Tags: general-topology

First, the preliminaries.

**Definition:** Given a nonempty set $X$, call a function $\mathscr{N}:X\to2^{2^X}$ a **neighborhood function** provided $\mathscr{N}$ satisfies the following properties.
\begin{align}
&\mbox{For every $x\in X$, $\mathscr{N}(x)\neq\{\emptyset\}$.}
\\[4pt]
&\mbox{If $U\in\mathscr{N}(x)$, then $x\in U$.}
\\[4pt]
&\mbox{If $U,V\in\mathscr{N}(x)$, then $U\cap V\in\mathscr{N}(x)$.}
\\[4pt]
&\mbox{If $U\in\mathscr{N}(x)$ and $V\subseteq X$ is such 
that $U\subseteq V$, then $V\in\mathscr{N}(x)$.}
\\[4pt]
\end{align}
Define $\tau_\mathscr{N}$, the topology induced by $\mathscr{N}$, by
\begin{align}
\tau_\mathscr{N}:=\{\mathscr{O}\subseteq X:\mathscr{O}\in\mathscr{N}(x)\mbox{ for every }x\in\mathscr{O}\}.
\end{align}

**Question:** Those are all the definitions we need.  It's not hard to show $\tau_\mathscr{N}$ is actually a topology on $X$.  Here is my question: given $x\in X$ and $N\in\mathscr{N}(x)$, does it follow that $N$ is actually a neighborhood of $x$?

**Attempts at a solution:** We wish to find $\mathscr{O}\subseteq X$ so that $\mathscr{O}\subseteq N$.  We can try
\begin{align}
\mathscr{O}:=\{y\in N:\exists N_y\in\mathscr{N}(y) s.t. N_y\subseteq N\}.
\end{align}
Which seems reasonable.  It's clear that $\mathscr{O}\subseteq N$, and also that $x\in\mathscr{O}$, but I can't show $\mathscr{O}$ is actually open.  In particular, given $y\in\mathscr{O}$, I want to find some $N_y\in\mathscr{N}(y)$ for which $N_y\subseteq\mathscr{O}$, but I only know there exists some $N_y\in\mathscr{N}(y)$ satisfying $N_y\subseteq N$.  Not good enough.

**Attempt 2:** Well, maybe a different $\mathscr{O}$ would work.  Try
\begin{align}
\mathscr{O}_2:=\{y\in N:\mathscr{O}\in\mathscr{N}(y)\}.
\end{align}
Again it's clear $\mathscr{O}_2\subseteq N$.  This time, it's easy to see $\mathscr{O}_2$ is open, but now I can't show $x$ is in it (or any other point, for that matter).

Long story short, with my first attempt I have a set which is nonempty but can't show it's open, with my second attempt I have a set which is open but I can't show it's nonempty.

My guess is either I have the wrong sets, or maybe it's not true.

EDIT: Follow-up question.  If they're not neighborhoods, what extra assumption can we put on $\mathscr{N}$ so that they are?

Comment: Extra assumption: For every $U \in \mathscr{N}(x)$ there is a $V\in \mathscr{N}(x)$ such that $U \in \mathscr{N}(y)$ for all $y \in V$. A neighbourhood of $x$ must also be a neighbourhood of all $y$ "close enough" to $x$.

Comment: Alright, trying to use this...
Fix $x\in X$ and $U\in\mathscr{N}$.  We want $U$ to contain an open set containing $x$.  Not many options, so take the $V$ as in the assumption.  Since $V\in\mathscr{N}(x)$, $V$ contains $x$.  Since $U\in\mathscr{N}(y)$ for every $y\in V$, $V\subseteq U$.  So far so good, but... I don't see how $V$ is open.  It doesn't seem to be a neighborhood of all of its points.

Comment: $V$ need not be open. But $\overset{\circ}{U} = \{ y : U \in \mathscr{N}(y)\}$ is open.

Comment: I don't see how $\mathring{U}=\{y:U\in\mathscr{N}(y)\}$.  In particular, using Unwisdom's example below, define $U:=X\setminus\{x_1\}$ for some $x_1\in X\setminus\{x_0\}$.  Then $U\in\mathscr{N}(x_0)$ since $x_0\in U$ and $\#(X\setminus U)=1<+\infty$, but $\mathring{U}$ is empty as $\tau_\mathscr{N}$ is the trivial topology.  However, I believe I did show $\mathring{U}\subseteq\{y:U\in\mathscr{N}(y)\}$.

Comment: Unwisdom's example doesn't satisfy the condition of my first comment. If $\mathscr{N}$ satisfies your conditions _and mine_, then $\mathscr{T} = \left\{ U \subset X : \bigl(\forall x \in U\bigr)\bigl(U \in \mathscr{N}(x)\bigr)\right\}$ is a topology such that $\mathscr{N}(x)$ is the family of $\mathscr{T}$-neighbourhoods of $x$ for all $x$, and $\{ y : U \in \mathscr{N}(y)\}$ is open then.

Comment: Sorry, even with all the conditions, I still don't see how, for a given $U$, $O:=\{x:U\in\mathscr{N}(x)\}$ is open.  For $O$ to be open, we need $O\in\mathscr{N}(x)$ for all $x\in O$.  So fix $x\in O$, thus $U\in\mathscr{N}(x)$.  Using your condition, there exists $V\in\mathscr{N}(x)$ for which $U\in\mathscr{N}(y)$ for all $y\in V$.  Here I'm stuck.  I don't see how to get inside $O$, so to speak. We could consider $W:=O\cap V$, which contains $x$ and satisfies $U\in\mathscr{N}(y)$ for every $y\in W$, but again, how to show $O\in\mathscr{N}(x)$, I don't know.

Comment: Then you have $V \subset O$. And $x\in V \subset O$ implies $O \in \mathscr{N}(x)$.

Comment: Ah-ha!  The $V\subseteq O$, that's the clue.  Thank you for your patience and guidance, fellow Daniel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, one minor correction: $\mathcal{N}:X\to\mathbf{2}^{\left(\mathbf{2}^{X}\right)}$.

Consider this example.  Let $X$ be some infinite set, and pick out $x_{0}\in X$. Let $\mathcal{N}(x_{0})$ be the set of cofinite subsets of $X$ that contain $x$, and for $x\neq x_{0}$, define $\mathcal{N}(x)=\{X\}$.

Take $N\in\mathcal{N}(x_{0})$ with $U\neq X$.  $N$ has no open subsets, and so cannot be a neighborhood.

Comment: Thanks!  Exactly what I needed.

I don't see how $\mathscr{N}$ takes values in $2^{2^X}$ though.  Given $x\in X$, $\mathscr{N}(x)$ outputs a collection of subsets of $X$ itself.

Comment: @danzibr: Wanted to write about same thing to you, but noticed a comment is already there. $X\rightarrow X$: a point to another point. $X\rightarrow 2^X$: a point to a subset of points of $X$. $X\rightarrow 2^{2^X}$: a point to a subset of subsets of $X$.

Comment: Oh, I see.  In my head I skipped the point to a subset of $X$ itself.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First started as comment, by not enough space.

With your definition $\mathscr{N}(x)$ and $\mathscr{N}(y)$ are completely independent. However, to be open you require that $\mathscr{O}$ belongs to *every* $\mathscr{N}(o)$ for $o\in\mathscr{O}$. It is easy to see, that you may have $N$ in $\mathscr{N}(x)$, but *all* other points' "filters" will be coarser than $N$, i.e. they will "start" at sets larger than $N$. In that case if $\{x\}$ by itself is not open, then there is no other open neighborhood in $N$.